# 80x86 status bits. In which register are they readable?

Tags: x86-16

There are status bits, which "set" the type of the next busoperation at the 80x86.

Is there any possibility to read those statusbits from any register? If so which one?
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know now that you can not get any information about those status bits from a register.